# Intersection of distinct maximal ideals in a commutative ring with identity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

If $R$ is a commutative ring with identity and $M_1, \dots, M_r$ are distinct maximal ideals in $R$, then show that $M_1\cap M_2 \cap \cdots \cap M_r = M_1M_2\cdots M_r$. Is this true if "maximal" is replaced by "prime"?

$M_1M_2\cdots M_r \subset M_1\cap M_2 \cap \cdots \cap M_r$ is trivial. 
Can you help me?

Comment: In a commutative ring $R$ with identity it is always true that, for any two ideal $I$ and $J$, $IJ \subseteq I \cap J.$ Also if $I + J = R,$ then $IJ = I \cap J.$

Comment: I explain * Krish*'s comment as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $I$ and $J$ be comaximal ($I+J=R$). then $IJ = I \cap J$, because:
$IJ \subseteq I \cap J.$ and
 $$I \cap J=(I \cap J)R=(I \cap J)(I+J)=(I \cap J)I+(I \cap J)J$$
but $  (I \cap J)I\subseteq JI $  and $  (I \cap J)J\subseteq IJ $. It follows that $  I \cap J\subseteq IJ.$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \\ \ \ \ \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \\  \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ._{proof \ from \ sharp}$

Comment: How'd we say that I+J=R?

Comment: I and J are comaximal. any two pair of maximals are comaximal.